# wxPython: Aligning the elements within two boxsizers

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to align two of the elements of the boxsizers, namely: "BIG BIG STRINNNNNNGGGGGGGGG" and "Measurement" so that they are under the same column like so:

```
hello world                                Measurement
oh no worldBIG BIG STRINNNNNNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

How can I achieve this by using the code below?

Reading the wxPython documentation it says the following:

> The ALIGN* flags allow you to specify the alignment of the item within
>   the space allotted to it by the sizer, adjusted for the border if any.

However that is not true in this case.

```
import wx
from imgtec import codescape
import wx.lib.inspection

class MyRegion(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="My Region")
        b1=wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        b2=wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)

        d1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="hello world")
        b1.Add(d1)
        d2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Measurement", style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        b1.Add(d2,
               flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND)

        c1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="oh no world")
        b2.Add(c1)
        c2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="BIG BIG STRINNNNNNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        b2.Add(c2,
           flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT| wx.EXPAND )

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        sizer.Add(item=b2, pos=(0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(item=b1, pos=(1,0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyRegion(None)
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a spacer between `d1` and `d2`:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class MyRegion(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="My Region")
        b1=wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        b2=wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)

        d1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="hello world")
        b1.Add(d1)

        b1.AddStretchSpacer()  # <-- ADD THE SPACER HERE

        d2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="Measurement", style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        b1.Add(d2,
               flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND)

        c1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="oh no world")
        b2.Add(c1)
        c2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="BIG BIG STRINNNNNNGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG",style=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        b2.Add(c2,
           flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT| wx.EXPAND )

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        sizer.Add(item=b2, pos=(0,0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(item=b1, pos=(1,0), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyRegion(None)
    frame.Show()
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Mike Driscoll already shows the way to do it correctly, I'd just like to add that there is a simple rule to keep in mind: alignment flags only work in transversal sizer direction, i.e. vertically for horizontal box sizers.

Future versions of wxWidgets will give errors when `wxALIGN_RIGHT` is used inside a horizontal sizer (and, similarly, `wxALIGN_TOP` or another vertical alignment inside a vertical one) because this can *never* work.

You can use alignment flags in both directions in 2D sizers such as `wx[Flex]GridSizer` however.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was wondering why the wx.ALIGN_RIGHT wasn't working. This makes sense :)